# Navigate between local HTML files using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how to swap from one page to another, both local files on my PC in a HTML file.

I guess I would be linking a button made in HTML to the script but unfortunately I don't know where to start.

The file I'm trying to navigate to is "About_Us.html"

Comment: What do you mean by swap from one page to another?

Comment: Can you include the code you've written so far? It sounds like you will want to use javascript to toggle between a hidden display and visible display of the second page. You will get better responses if you copy in your code :)

Comment: This was very helpful to me when I started on stackoverflow sscce.org

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [href](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) attribute.

```
<a href="About_Us.html">Visible Text Here</a>
<!-- You might need to use a different path if the file is in a different directory, for example href="../About_Us.html" -->
```

A quick way to use a button to do this

```
<input type=button onClick="location.href='About_Us.html'" value='Visible Text Here'>
```

Comment: How would i put that into a clickable button using the <button> </button> tags?

Comment: <button> <a href="About_Us.html"> About Us </a> </button>

Comment: I just included one way to do that

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you want a script that can load any random `.html` on your computer, but then also switch back...

**Use iFrames**
You can have buttons that switch the `src` attribute of the iframes..
check out this js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ProgrammerKid/p0kktLdj/

all im doing is changing the "src" of the "iframe" using jQuery (a really useful JS library you should learn)

---

## Example

Two buttons... 1 iFrame...

```
<iframe src="no_where_yet"></iframe>
```

#### 1st button: changes iFrame to go to cnn.com

changes:

```
<iframe src="no_where_yet"></iframe>
```

to:

```
<iframe src="http://cnn.com"></iframe>
```

#### 2nd button: Changes iFrame to go to w3schools.com

changes:

```
<iframe src="http://cnn.com"></iframe>
```

to:

```
<iframe src="http://w3schools.com"></iframes>
```

Comment: I have a feeling this is more to what i want but unfortunatly i dont quite understand what you mean, the part where you have put  "and then in about.html, have <a href="index.html">Go back home</a>... " i know how to do that, i would class myself as competent in HTML but i have no idea what you are on about

Comment: I modified my answer... i made it simpler... read the example I just added.. I tried to explain it better... because when you modify an <iframe></iframe> src attribute, it doesn't reload the webpage, it only reloads the iframe with the new website

Comment: Cheers, Ok that made it easier but unfortuantly no that is not what i wanted, cheers anyway, looks like im going to have to stick with good ol' <a href> tags for now untill i get better at what im doing, thanks